# Trouble with deadlisting

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have searched and searched about deadlisting, but to my avail - i have found few sites but i don't think they are very helpful :P

Could somebody explain briefly what it is, and maybe how to do it, if you could refer me to a site which explains in an easy manner i would be grateful.

an example of code one could deadlist:

```
\x90\xb8\x02\x00\x00\x00\x83\xf8\x03\x74\x07\xb8\x73\x80\x04\x08\xeb\x01\xd8\x31\xc0\x50\xbb\x9e\x9a\x9a\x99\xf7\xdb\x53\xbb\x9c\x9a\x9e\x9b\xf7\xdb\x53\x90\xcc
```

Comment: Apparently that's simply disassembling. Use any disassembler, such as ndisasm.

Comment: oh, well thanks for the quick response!

Comment: This code contains a trivial anti-disassembly trick (conditionally jumping halfway into an instruction with a condition that is always false), so take care when disassembling. In some disassemblers, you may have to replace the d8 by 90 to stop it from misaligning the instruction stream.